# Definition of integers in higher-order logic

Tags: integers, higher-order-logic

There's the classical of natural numbers in higher-order logic (see the introduction of [this page](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/) for example).

Is there something similar for integers (elements of $\mathbb{Z}$) ? I didn't find this on internet.

And what about rational and real numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. To be precise, say that a second-order-logic sentence $\psi$ **characterizes** a structure $\mathcal{A}$ iff the structures in which $\psi$ is true are exactly the structures isomorphic to $\mathcal{A}$, and say that a structure $\mathcal{A}$ is **second-order characterizable** iff such a $\psi$ exists. Here are some examples:

- $\mathbb{R}$ (with addition and multiplication) is the unique-up-to-isomorphism Dedekind-complete orderable field.
- $\mathbb{Q}$ (with addition and multiplication) is the unique-up-to-isomorphism infinite divisible orderable abelian group with no nontrivial proper divisible subgroup.
- $\mathbb{Q}$  (with ordering alone) is the unique-up-to-isomorphism countable dense linear order without endpoints (this is due to Cantor).
- $\mathbb{Z}$ (with addition and multiplication) is the unique-up-to-isomorphism orderable ring with no proper subring.
- $\mathbb{Z}$ (with ordering alone) is the unique-up-to-isomorphism nonempty linear order without endpoints in which all intervals between elements are finite.

Each of these descriptions is straightforwardly convertible into a second-order characterizing sentence.

Interestingly, every naturally-occurring mathematical structure seems to be second-order characterizable; this theme is discussed in Vaananen's paper [*Second-order logic or set theory?*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41472441#metadata_info_tab_contents), which I recommend. Moreover, it is undecidable from the usual axioms of set theory whether every *countable* structure is second-order characterizable (see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161676/the-non-absoluteness-of-second-order-elementary-equivalence)).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. But does this definition permit kind of a natural embedding of the HOL-naturals into the HOL-integers? (I know this wasn't mentioned in my question)

Comment: I guess it just has to be constructed imposing 0 to be the +-identity of the ring of integers and successor to be +1 function (where 1 is the x-identity)

Comment: @Zlotz Yup. Also, note that even in a first-order way you can define the nonnegative integers in the ring of integers: an integer $z$ is nonnegative iff there are integers $a,b,c,d$ with $$z=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$$ (the "if" is the nontrivial part - this is [Lagrange's four square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem)).

Comment: And x∈E is simulated by E(x): Prop ?